# How to check for null / default values in Anchor Struct?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, publickey

I have the following struct in my anchor program.

```
pub struct CustomStruct {
    pub user: Pubkey,
    pub number: u64
}
```

How would I go about checking for null values / default values for user and number?

I'm assuming for u64, I can check u64 == u64(0) or something similar.

Not sure how to check for null Pubkey.

Comment: Hmm... what's your larger goal here? Are you trying to determine if an account has already been initialized? If so, you could add a boolean property to your struct and use that as a flag. But more generally, you should only initialize accounts once (in the instruction where you tag them with `init`). All other instructions can then assume the account is already initialized.

Comment: got it- yeah boolean could work but I'd prefer to not add additional fields if not needed. the larger goal is that I want the anchor program to have an if else statement if the account is or is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initialize an account with that structure and don't specify the pubkey, the default value will be `"111111111111111111111111111111111"`, which is the system program.